# Google cloud load balancer dynamically adding backend buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, cloud-security, signed-url

**Goal**:
For example, users could create courses which has resources such as images, videos etc.
I want to restrict access to them using signed cookies. i.e. resources on /courses/1 will only be accessible to logged-in users who have a valid signed cookie.

**Background**
I'll be creating a bucket of media files per course based on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#recommended_bucket_architecture.

**Where I am stuck**

- How to add backend buckets to the load balancer dynamically since I could only add them in the console
- How to use the same signing key for all buckets for easy maintenance https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-cookies#creatingkeys. It seems like I need to manually create a key for each bucket.

So is there a standard way to do these or am I thinking about this whole architecture wrong since this won't scale without automation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be limited to [50 path rules as mentioned in the Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#url_maps), limited to 50 courses. I hope you expect more than this!!

So, this pattern isn't suitable for your use case. You need to use the same bucket and to control access with a backend app. And then to [generated SignedUrl](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) for the resources requested by the users

Comment: Thanks for your insight! I was reallly hoping there would be a proven way to do this, especially since using signed urls for a lot of resources also doesn't sound great as explained in the docs.